# How to install Node.js on Windows 10?

Tags: node.js, windows, installation, node.js-client

I tried to install Node.js on the Windows 10 64 bit using installer.

When I run installe.exe I accept rules and push next button, in any case I get the following notification:
[image]

When I tried to set path of downloaded install file:

[image]

And get this error again.

Answer (score 0):

**@Babaev**  *From what you said, I guess its a problem related to path issue or rather the .msi file may have been corrupted on download. Try the windows binary that is .exe file from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ let's say we have the node.exe file located in the folder c:\nodejs. Now to setup npm-*

> Step 1: Download the latest npm release from
>   GitHub(https://github.com/npm/npm/releases)  Step 2:Create folders
>   c:\nodejs\node_modules and :\nodejs\node_modules\npm
>   Step 3:Unzip the
>   downloaded zip file in c:\nodejs\node_modules\npm folder 
>   Step 4:Copy
>   npm and npm.cmd files from c:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin to c:\nodejs
>   folder.
>   Step 5: As the final step you can add node's folder
>   pathc:\nodejs to the path environment variable so that you don't have
>   to specify full path when running node.exe and npm at command prompt.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have downloaded exe package, when I run it opens cmd window

Comment: Thank you, but where can i add path  environment variable and what value?